# How to pass float array to glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

i'm working on OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders on android...

i have a float array with position of vertices along with other attributes of vertices.
position and other attributes may change over time.

how can i pass this modified array to glVertexAttribPointer,
so that i can draw the scene with updated values

when i tried to pass it, i got

> The method glVertexAttribPointer(int, int, int, boolean, int, Buffer) in the type GLES20 is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, boolean, int, float[])

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to take that array of float vertexes you have and somehow convert it into a buffer object.  I'm no openGL expert, so thats as far as I can answer this.

Comment: thanx Eric, but i cant modify the buffer... so want to use arrays intead

Answer (score 2):

```
FloatBuffer yourFloatBuffer;
float[] yourFloatArray;    

FloatBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(yourFloatArray.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    yourFloatBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    yourFloatBuffer.put(yourFloatArray);
    yourFloatBuffer.position(0);
```

This should work.

Comment: this works Egor, i know that. but i want to modify the float array later during runtime...   with this code i can't achieve

Comment: I thinks, you should perform this code everytime you change the array.

Comment: ya we can do that, but the problem is when i pass the buffer to shader, GPU might be using it and i dont have control over it... may be thats why i'm getting exception

Answer (score 0):

Is it java.nio.Buffer? Because it seems you need

```
java.nio.FloatBuffer
```

and call floatBuffer.array()

to get the float[] array out of it.

But, obviously it is final in FloatBuffer.java:

```
final float[] hb;
```

So it seems that you'll need to... maybe extend FloatBuffer and make the array non-final.